# bootstrap datepicker not selecting date in post variable

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

> Code for datepicker.

```
    <form action="xyz.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textarea"> From Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="bfh-datepicker" >
                        <input id="dateFrom" type="text" name="dateFrom"  class="datepicker">
                   </div>

                </div>  
          <button type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
```

> Code for fetching value in php

```
       if(isset($_POST['create'])){
          echo $fromDate=$_POST['dateFrom'];

            }
```

> I want date in my post variable. but its giving me error "Notice: Undefined index: dateFrom in line....."

Comment: Post your full code with form tag.

Comment: updated..check now

Comment: Where is `create`?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to get the value:

```
$('#dateForm').val()
```

or

```
$('#dateForm').date('date')
```

and see the way you can pass this value to the BE.

Comment: where should i add this lines ?

Comment: This code is all that you need to get the value of the datepicker, then you can do a bunch of things to send it to Back End..

1) Use AJAX, and specify the value of each field in the data property.
2) subscribe to datepicker changes   subscribing  to the "changedDate" event of the picker. 

I will update my answer with the second option